# Remove a specific character from string

Tags: c#

I have an application

```
namespace Aplikacija1
{
    public class excercise5
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {         
            Console.WriteLine("Enter word :");
            string word = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the letter :");
            string letter = Console.ReadLine();
            int charPos = word.IndexOf($"{letter}");
            Console.WriteLine(word.Remove(charPos, 1));
        }
    }
}
```

so it should remove a letter from the string which is entered.

If I enter word Nikola and letter a the result is Nikol which is correct

But if I enter word Nikala and the letter a the result is Nikla, with no option to remove second a, or choose which a I want to remove

Is there a way to add something to my code to make it work?

Comment: The question is not about Visual Studio - please remove the tag.

Comment: There's no point to using string interpolation like this `$"{letter}"` the result is effectiveky the same as just using the variable on it's own - `letter`

Comment: "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)" might help.

Comment: thanks all, definitely no need for $..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C.Evenhuis has told you what you need to do to get the result you want, but I just wanted to point out why your first attempt didn't work..

`Remove`, in the way you used it, is something like a short way of saying `RemoveEverythingAfter` - it's used for cutting large parts out of strings, and is something like the the opposite of `Substring`. It isn't normally used for repeatedly removing individual characters or small parts. It cuts out and discards a section of a string, whereas `Substring` cuts out and keeps parts of a string

Think about string indexes as being between the letters:

```
 h e l l o _ w o r l d
^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1011
```

If you say `Remove(7)` it will remove everything from 7 onwards (towards the right, so, 8, 9 ...):

```
 h e l l o _ w o r l d
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^
    Keep        Remove


var hw = "hello_world";
Console.Print(hw.Remove(7)); //prints: hello_w
```

If you said `Substring(7)` it *keeps* everything from 7 onwards

```
 h e l l o _ w o r l d
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^
    Remove      Keep

var hw = "hello_world";
Console.Print(hw.Substring(7)); //prints: orld
```

---

`Substring` and `Remove` also have a form where they take a second parameter for the number of chars to keep or remove

If you said `Substring(4, 3)` it keeps a length of 3 from index 4, so keeping chars between 4 and 7. If you say `Remove(4, 3)` it removes 3 chars between 4 and 7

```
 h e l l o _ w o r l d
 ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^ ^^^^^^^               Substring(4, 3)
 Remove  Keep  Remove            --> result: o_w

 h e l l o _ w o r l d
 ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^ ^^^^^^^               Remove(4, 3)
 Keep    Remove  Keep            --> result: hellorld
```

**All in, `Remove` wasn't really what you wanted, because it's for cutting out *ranges*, not all occurrences of one char/string**

You could have used Remove repeatedly to remove one char at a time, while that char was still found in the string but it's incredibly tedious/low performance:

```
for(var idx = word.IndexOf(letter); idx > -1; idx = word.IndexOf(letter))
  word = word.Remove(idx, 1);
```

---

Footnote: Modern C# has another, more compact way of doing Substring just using indexes:

```
var hw = "hello_world";
hw[4..]  //keep from index 4 to end, i.e. o_world
hw[..4]  //keep from start to index 4, i.e. hell
hw[^4..] //keep from "4 back from end" to end, i.e. orld
hw[..^4] //keep from start to "4 back from end", i.e. hello_w
hw[7..10] //keep between 7 and 10, i.e. orl
hw[4..^4] //keep between 4 from start and 4 from end, i.e. o_w
hw[^8..8] //keep between 8 from end and 8 from start, i.e. lo_wo
```

And so on..

Comment: I find Substring to be incredibly annoying because it throws exceptions. No string manipulation method should do that.

Comment: Indeed; how many codebases do you see where there is an extension method that doesn't crash out of bounds.. Still, at least extension methods are a thing, and it's slightly better these days than it was; always used to irritate me that `Remove(str.Length)` crashed and `Substring(str.Length)` didn't, but netcore/5 at least returns str if you Remove the length..

Comment: Delphi has string manipulation functions that don't throw exceptions. If for example you try to copy partly or entirely out of range, you just get what is logical - what you can get, or empty. That's a very good way to work with strings. The new slice functions work that way at least in F#, and I assume also in C#.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-6.0#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_) method and replace it with an empty string:

```
string wordWithoutLetter = word.Replace(letter, "");
Console.WriteLine(wordWithoutLetter);
```

Comment: Yes, that's for both, thank you 
what about just wanting to remove the second a, not both of them

Comment: Just change `IndexOf` with `LastIndexOf`